Module parse failed:
Failed to compile.
Error in ./~/@mui/system/colorManipulator.js

Module parse failed:
/home/abate/Desktop/React/react-mui/node_modules/@mui/system/colorManipulator.js
Unexpected token (220:67) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
this file type. SyntaxError: Unexpected token (220:67)  @
./~/@mui/material/node/Button/Button.js 16:24-63

I use npx create-react-app to create the application and npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled  I expected to work but it doesn't work i try to fix manually first delete the node module package and package-lock.json and re instal

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Could you give the version of NodeJS that you are currently running? Also it's best if you provide a snippet of your code to help people understand how you are using these external modules.

why @emotion/react and not vanilla react?
